# How can I control Vagrant from an ansible playbook?

Tags: go, ansible, vagrant, provisioning, vagrantfile

I am currently working on my final degree project and I have been asked to create a platform in which I have to generate a Vagrantfile (in general control vagrant) from an ansible playbook. Ansible will be running on a golang module. Then, once the Vagrantfile is generated, ansible will be used again to provision all the machines.

My question comes when I have to generate this Vagrantfile and control all vagrant commands, arguments... from the ansible playbook. I have tried to search an ansible module but they do not exist. I found out that the community made one module for ansible that tries to do the work but it is horrible to understand and it does not seem to work.

Is it possible to execute vagrant from an ansible playbook? Would it be a better idea to generate all vagrant information in the golang module instad of using ansible to do that work?

Thank you!

Comment: I guess this page, of the Vagrant documentation answers your question: https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_intro#host-variables

Comment: If I don't get it right @β.εηοιτ.βε this documentation only works if you already have Vagrant and you are trying to provision the created machines. My question has to do when you are generating the vagrant file but you do it with ansible. It has nothing to do on how ansible provisions vagrant once the machines are created. The idea is to generate vagrant from ansible in your localhost.

Comment: Mhm, I see. Then just template the Vagrantfile with Jinja (using loops and all) and you should have what you expect.